# duplicate cols of matrix without changing rows

Tags: r

I have a matrix with 54675 rows and 2 col..... I want to have a matrix with 54675 rows(same and NOT changed ) and 4 col(one by one)
what should I do?

for example..

```
dim(ex)
[1] 54675     2

dim(ex)
[1] 5475   4
```

Comment: Maybe `ex[,c(1,2,1,2)]` would work for you?

Comment: yes...it work...tnx